# Calculate turning Points for Contours in C#

Tags: c#, halcon

I am find out the Image Coutours by Halcon,then I will determine turning Points
in Contours (x,y).
The following figures
[Contour Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJWdu.png)
I reference the [calculate turning points / pivot points in trajectory (path)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631776/calculate-turning-points-pivot-points-in-trajectory-path)
Use Ramer-Douglas-Peucker(RDP) algorithm and the Result
[RDP Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEr01.png)
I Want to get the Result follwing figures
[I Want Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLYfa.png)

```
public class Douglas
{
    public  List<Point> DouglasThinningMachine(List<Point> spList,double threshold=10)
    {
        if (spList == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(spList));
        }
        
        int max = spList.Count;
        int location = 0;

        Stack<int> A = new Stack<int>();
        Stack<int> B = new Stack<int>();
        A.Push(0);
        B.Push(max - 1);
        do
        {
            var d = FindMostDistance(spList, A.Peek(), B.Peek(), ref location);
            if (d > threshold)
            {
                B.Push(location);
            }
            else
            {
                A.Push(location);
                B.Pop();
            }
        } while (B.Count > 0);
        List<int> listOfIndex = A.ToList();
        listOfIndex.Sort();
        List<Point> result = new List<Point>();
        foreach (int index in listOfIndex)
        {
            result.Add(spList[index]);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private  double FindMostDistance(List<Point> seriesPoints, int start, int end, ref int location)
    {
        if (end - start <= 1)
        {
            location = end;
            return 0;
        }
        double result = 0;
        Point startPoint = seriesPoints[start];
        Point endPoint = seriesPoints[end];
        for (int i = start + 1; i < end; i++)
        {
            
            var d = GetDistanceToLine(startPoint, endPoint, seriesPoints[i]);
            if (d > result)
            {
                result = d;
                location = i;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    

    public  double GetDistanceToLine(double p1x, double p1y, double p2x, double p2y, double refpx, double refpy)
        => Math.Abs(((p2y - p1y) * (refpx - p1x)) - ((refpy - p1y) * (p2x - p1x))) / Math.Pow(((p2y - p1y) * (p2y - p1y)) + ((p2x - p1x) * (p2x - p1x)), 0.5);

    public  double GetDistanceToLine(Point point1, Point point2, Point refPoint)
    {
        return GetDistanceToLine(point1.X, point1.Y, point2.X, point2.Y, refPoint.X, refPoint.Y);
    }


}
```

Main Code:

```
 List<Point> PP = new List<Point>();

        for (int i = 0; i < XX.Count; i++)
        {
            PP.Add(new Point() { X = Convert.ToInt32(XX[i]), Y = Convert.ToInt32(yy[i]) });
        }
        Douglas dg = new Douglas();
        var ggg = dg.DouglasThinningMachine(PP,10);
       

       for (int i = 0; i < XX.Count; i++)
        {
            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(XX[i], yy[i]);
        }

       foreach( var g in ggg)
        {
            chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(g.X,g.Y);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < XX.Count; i++)
        {
            chart1.Series[2].Points.AddXY(XX[i], result[i]);
        }
```

[Contour Data Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bzflCEA4Sl3K6g_FJ_lcX5R53G6x5ia1/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Read *.csv file in Halcon:
open_file (Path, 'input', FileHandle)
fread_line (FileHandle, OutLine, IsEOF)
tuple_split (OutLine, ',', Substrings)
tuple_str_first_n (Substrings[|Substrings|-1], strlen(Substrings[|Substrings|-1])-2, Substring)
Substrings[|Substrings|-1] := Substring
tuple_number (Substrings, Result)
close_file (FileHandle)

// Generate contours and split them
gen_contour_polygon_xld (Contour, -Y, X)
gen_polygons_xld (Contour, Polygons, 'ramer', 5)
split_contours_xld (Polygons, Contours, 'polygon', 3, 5)
```

You can adjust the parameters in gen_polygons_xld and split_contours_xld to get the connections you'd like.

[image]